# Convert an array of strings into an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a question about the best way to convert each element into an array of String to `Int`.

The input value is like

```
["1","2","","","x"]
```

for each element needed to convert to `Int` (when if possible) when the value is `""` should return `0`. When the value is imposible to convert to Int removed from the array.

I have this code. But I looking improve it.

```
func convertValues(_ number: [String]) -> [Int] {

    let int: [Int] = number.map{ (current) -> Int in
       if current == "" {
           return 0
       }

       return Int(current)!
      }
      return int
 }
```

And return an array of Int.

Comment: What value should it return to the "x" element of your input? Note that  Int(current)! would crash your app if you pass an invalid value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `compactMap` instead of `map` and just use a predicate to check if the current element is an empty string. If `true`, return zero. Otherwise, return the result of initializing a new integer from a string (it will automatically discard invalid input):

---

```
func convertValues(_ number: [String]) -> [Int] {
    number.compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? .zero : Int($0) }
}
```

---

```
convertValues(["1","2","","","x"])  // [1, 2, 0, 0]
```